# OnTimeChangedListener is not working in 5.0.0, 5.0.1 and 5.02

Tags: android-activity

I am implementing Time Picker using Material Designing for Lolipop in a XML. OnTimeChangedListener is working fine in nexus device but when I am testing it on Motorola handset having OS 5.0.2 OnTimeChangedListener is not firing up. Can anyone help me how to Resolve it. Here is my java file.

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTimeChangedListener {

```
/** Private members of the class */
private TextView displayTime;
private Button pickTime;

private int pHour;
private int pMinute;
TimePicker picker;
private String am_pm;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    picker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.time);
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mHour = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int mMinute = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    picker.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);
}

OnTimeChangedListener listener = new OnTimeChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pHour = hourOfDay;
        pMinute = minute;
        System.out.println("pHour" + pHour);
        System.out.println("pMinute" + pMinute);
    }
};



@Override
public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    pHour = hourOfDay;
    pMinute = minute;
    System.out.println("pHour" + pHour);
    System.out.println("pMinute" + pMinute);

}
```

}

Comment: Hey have you found solution ?? i am facing same problem

Comment: Me too, Maybe using an older time picker? :/